# testing android app on different devices

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-screen-support, android-screen

I am developing one android application & planning to use it on android phones and tablets. Currently I am testing it with help of avd (Galaxy nexus). To use it on different devices with different sizes and densities, I want to test it on different avds.

My problem is instead of setting number of devices, can anybody suggest me few common avds whose configurations will cover most of standard devices (small, normal, large, xlarge).

In my eclipse, I am getting some nexus avds(10, s, one, 4, 7 etc) and some other devices( like 10.1"wxga, 5.4"fwvga etc etc). I am using adt bundle provided by google.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use Samsung Remote testing lab.It provide to test your apps on different screen resolutions and also with the devices that do support temperature sensor etc.Please follow this [link](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/).I dont have any temperature sensor mobile but i need to test in one of my project.So i use Samsung galaxy Tab 3 for this purpose and also for some other things.I have also shown you the output.If you still need any help comment here.I think this might helps you :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to figure out which sort of devices you are going to target.

[This link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) may be helpful to figuring out what type of filter you want to use in order to decide the targeted devices.

For most of the UI part you can rely on the AVDs provided by the Google Bundle choose the desired test AVDs (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi).

But you should be ready for the surprises because some devices behave differently than the others. I mean the same build may be working fine for most of the devices but for a particular device the UI behavior may be different.

All the best.